# Use tail directly on website data, or another utility needed?

Tags: linux, awk, tail

I am planning to extract a single field of data from the last line of data on a website to populate an RRD database.  I'm running Linux.

The website is: http://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=201309250000&block=03895 (it's airport meteorological data).

Questions: can I use `tail` to *directly* read the last line of data from the website, or do I need to read the data using another utility and then use `tail` to get the last line? 
Is `awk` the best utility for separating out the nth field of data from that line? (I'm not familar with Perl).

Thanks.
Nigel.

Comment: Since the main question is answered, yes - `awk` is probably the best tool for that part, very easy to use for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to disable `curl`'s stderr output which shows network data, and then just pipe to `tail`:

```
$ url="http://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=201309250000&block=03895"
$ curl "$url" 2>/dev/null | tail -n 1
03895,2013,11,28,15,00,AAXX 28154 03895 41450 82702 10090 20076 40342 56014 70252 885// 333 86613=
```

You can leave out the `2>/dev/null` if you want—it won't matter for `tail`, but it's nicer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

No, tail will not read from the network, but wget, curl, or snarf will. Each of those programs can download and save the remote file or download and print to standard out. then tail and awk (which if you know it will do just fine) come into play.